# Sonata admin, global Access per ROLE not using FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to have it so i can define the actions per role in symfony2

this is what i currently have

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MEMBER: ROLE_GUEST
        ROLE_STAFF: ROLE_MEMBER
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_SONATA_OWNER, ADMIN, OWNER]
```

and

```
sonata_admin:
    #title_logo: bundles/acmedemo/img/fancy_acme_logo.png
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
        # acl security information
        information:
            GUEST:    []
            STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]
            OWNER:    [OWNER]
        # permissions not related to an object instance and also to be available when objects do not exist
        # the DELETE admin permission means the user is allowed to batch delete objects
        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
        # permission related to the objects
        object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
```

i am looking for something that makes me able to grant ROLE_ADMIN the SONATA ROLE OWNER for example, i really have no idea on how to do this and the sonata documentation is more adapted to the FOSUserBundle which i am not using.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to grant ROLE_ADMIN to all users who already have ROLE_SONATA_OWNER, you can do this by modifying your role hierarchy (cf. [the Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)' "Hierarchical Roles" section) to this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MEMBER:       ROLE_GUEST
    ROLE_STAFF:        ROLE_MEMBER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_STAFF, ADMIN, OWNER]
    ROLE_SONATA_OWNER: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Comment: I am trying to grant all SONATA roles to my ROLE_ADMIN, however i dont know how to specify the SONATA roles, when i generate the list it gives me a specific ROLE per admin service which is quite a lot of work for just giving for example, the CREATE action to the ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Well, I don't know SONATA, so it seems I can't help you then. Good luck. :)